# permissions for apache user

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, file-permissions

I have apache set to the `_www` user account. Every time I create a file in the site directory, It's getting created with owner/group of `myusername` / `wheel`, so apache doesn't have access to it and I have to go `chown`+`chmod` the folder/files. Looking for either a "correct" setup or any suggestions.

This is a development machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a group called `www-admin` and add yourself and apache to it. When you work on the website, change your active group to `www-admin` and make sure the files are readably by group. You'll still own the files, but Apache will have correct access to them. [Here's a guide on Unix Groups](http://www.udel.edu/topics/os/unix/general/unixgroups.html).

If this machine has more than one user, you could also consider moving to using per-user web directories and setting up Apache with `su-exec` so it'll run as the user that owns the directory. This probably isn't necessary or useful on most dev machines, though (this is the setup that shared hosting companies use).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd still have the same issue if doing anything outside of terminal, e.g. from finder / photoshop

Comment: You might be best off going the su_exec way, then (which I just edited in). Documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html